# Sentry does not upload hints with `captureException(exception, dynamic hint)` when throwing an error manually in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, sentry

I want to add a String containing a verbose stack trace of the programs path leading up to the failure and decided to add it to the `hint` argument in the method

```
static Future<SentryId> captureException(
    dynamic throwable, {
    dynamic stackTrace,
    dynamic hint,
    ScopeCallback? withScope,
  })
```

I call it like this:

```
Sentry.captureException(Exception('MyException'), hint: 'this is what happened...');
```

However I cant find any sign of "hints" in the web client.
Am I doing it right and if so where can I find it?

Comment: Hint is used to process the event. It doesn't get went to sentry.
You can add data directly to the event. Or in the beforeSend, read data from the hint and change the event

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. We ended up using the `captureMessage()` instead and passing the "hint" as the message string.